# Understanding effective object creation

Tags: java, spring

J. Bloch wrote the following about object creation:

> Conversely, avoiding object creation by maintaining your own object
>   pool is a bad idea unless the objects in the pool are extremely
>   heavyweight

So, using spring beans being created inside the container may cause some harm if we start creating too much beans declaratively. For instance, I supply the insstance of a `Factory` object by the declration:

```
<bean id="userFactory" class="com.foo.factory.UserFactory">
    <property name="creatorMap">
        <!-- map's declaration -->
    </property>
</bean>

public class UserFactory{
     Map<UserType, Creator> creators;

     public User create(UserType t){

         return creators.get(t).create();
     }
}

public enum UserType{
    VIP,
    GUEST,
    ACTIVE,
    //etc
}

public interface Creator{
    public User create();
}
```

Isn't it a bad idea to declare such factories within the spring beans?

Comment: What are your concerns about creating this kind of factories?

Comment: @Ajan Because in projects I may have hundreds of different factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the context of Joshua's suggestion is expensive to create objects - `extremely heavyweights`. You create object pools to reuse and avoid expensive creation for e.g., things like
connection pool etc. The framework you are referring to (Spring) itself uses  lots of such Factories inside it's infrastructure code. So in my opinion it should
boil down to whether you require such factories in your application. Each application thread using such factory would create it's own contextual object and the number would depend upon such requests to the factory bean.

Comment: So, it's not going to be harmful to use such factories, is it?

Comment: Your use case does not seem to be creating very expensive objects so these should be fine. If you do not create these factories in Spring container you would create it elsewhere and will loose any benefit you might get from container managed factories.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I need to use different factories (containing the different maps of creators) for different projects. That's why I decided to do so...